# How can I run badblocks and smartctl over SSH, close SSH without interrupting badblocks and smartctl?

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a server with a hard drive I'd like to test using smartctl (smartmontools) and badblocks.
I would use smartctl first, then badblocks.

My question is three parts:

1. How can I run the commands over SSH so the process won't stop when I close the Terminal?
2. How can I output the badblocks results and the smartctl info to a file?
3. How can I run smartctl and then badblocks will start automatically (when smartctl is finished) without having to SSH again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although I detect a serious lack of research effort, here’s an answer.

1. `nohup` wraps a process so that it doesn’t receive the hangup (HUP) signal. As such, it will continue running after the session is closed.

   For more sophisticated features, you could use `screen` or `tmux`, which work much like a disconnected remote desktop session on Windows. Programs keep running and the output is collected. It will be presented to you when you reconnect to the `screen`/`tmux` session.
2. Output redirection is the keyword here, with the corresponding operator being `>` as in `echo bla > file.txt`.
3. You don’t. That’s because it’s not actually `smartctl` doing the test, but the hard drive itself. There is no notification when it’s finished, you have to poll for status/results periodically.

Comment: Wouldn’t `(smartctl && badblocks) &` answer question 3? (Or at least `nohup sh -c 'smartctl && badblocks' &`, or running a script that does `smartctl && badblocks` with `nohup` and `&`?)

Comment: No, it doesn’t. He wants to run a SMART self-test on the hard drive. This test is *started* by `smartctl`, which exits immediately. The test is executed by the drive itself. Its status can be polled.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to log in via SSH, and then start `screen`.

Within `screen`, run the commands like this:

```
 smartctl <options>; badblocks <options>
```

Now, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to "detach" from the `screen` session. That way it will keep running when you close SSH.

You can "reattach" the `screen` session when you log in again later by running `screen -r`.

If you still want to save the command's output to a file, run them like this:

```
(smartctl <options>; badblocks <options>) >/path/to/log/file.txt
```